# Notify Windows of a file change made by Java

Tags: java, windows

I have a java program that at some point creates a file in a certain directory.
Another program which is not written by me is detecting changes on this directory and acts accordingly.

The file created is a very small text file around 1KB.

Sometimes the program couldnt detect the new file.
If I copy the same file manually from windows, the program detects without a problem.

Is there a way for me to tell windows.... " LOOK! this file is created...."  ?

Thanks

I have tried with BufferedWriter , no change.
I have tried with
String command="cmd /c copy "+fileName+" "+fileNamefinal;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

The last one is better but still misses some files.

Comment: I suspect you may be dealing with an occurrence of the XY problem: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: If windows doesn't know that a file was changed, the file wasn't changed. There is either a bug in the program writing the file or in the the program scanning for new files.

Comment: Or may be the other program fault, or the file is locked. Do you know how the other program detects changes to files?

Comment: I dont know how other program detects. When I create the file in the directory, it doesnt detect. I move the file from the directory to somewhere else and then re - move it to the directory, the other program detects the file correctly.  I also tried to create the file somewhere else and copy the file to the directory from java as explained above. Same result.